# In Linux, how do I find find directory with the most subdirectories or files?

Tags: linux

How can I find the directory with the largest number of files/subdirectories in it on the system? Obviously the clever answer is `/`, but that's not what I'm looking for.

I’ve been told the filesystem is out of nodes, so I suspect that somewhere there are a lot of files/directories which are just garbage, and I want to find them.

I’ve tried running this:

```
$ find /home/user -type d -print | wc -l
```

to find specific directories.

Comment: Specify your question a bit more, since like you said, it's pretty much a landfall with `/` - do you want to find the most based on a specific starting directory (i.e. `/usr`, `/bin`, `/home`)?

Comment: "but that's not what I'm looking for"—what *are* you looking for?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

starting from the current directory, you could try

```
find . -type d | cut -d/ -f 2 | uniq -c
```

This will list all directories starting from the current one, split each line by the character "/", select field number "2" (each line starts with "./", so your first field would be ".") and then only outputs unique lines, and a count how often this unique line appears (-c parameter).

You could also add an "sort -g" at the end.

Comment: `find . -type f` to find the directory with the most files.