# How to find subdirectory of some directory, which have most files

Tags: linux, csh, tcsh

I have already done it using `bash`, but how can i get name or path to this subdirectory using `tcsh`. Later i need to count total size of all files in this subdirectory, please help me.

For example:

someDirectory

--firstDirectory

----file11.txt

----file12.txt

----file13.txt

--secondDirectory

----file21.txt

--thirdDirectory

----file31.txt

----file32.txt

----file33.txt

----file34.txt

----file35.txt

And as result i want to get path to the thirdDirectory, cause it have most files.

**Update**

Bash-solution

```
#!/bin/bash -f 

declare -i maxcount=0
declare -i count
declare maxdirectory

find someFolder -type d | while read DIR;
    do let count=`(ls $DIR | wc -w)`
    if(($count > $maxcount)); then 
        let maxcount=count 
        maxdirectory="$DIR"
    fi 
done
```

**Update**

Tcsh-solution

```
cd $1
foreach x(*)
    if(-d $x) then
    set count = `(ls $x -1 | wc -l)`
        if($count > $maxcount) then
            set directory = $x
            set maxcount = $count
        endif
    endif
end
```

Comment: how did you do it in bash? `du` is a nice command...

Comment: Fredrik, before i count total size of files i need to get folder in which i want to count it, but i cant do it with `tcsh` I must do all of this using only `tcsh`

Answer (score 2):

You can use cut:

```
find . | rev | cut -d "/" -f2- | rev | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1n,1 | tail -n1
```

Or awk:

```
find . | awk -F "/" '{for(i=1;i<=NF-1;i++) printf $i"/"; printf "\n"}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1n,1 | tail -n1
```

The file size in the identified directory you can get with:

```
du -s
```

or:

```
ls -lh | head -n1
```

Somebody asked a similar question, but unfortunately it was closed: [In Linux, how do I find find directory with the most subdirectories or files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001672/in-linux-how-to-find-directory-with-most-subdirectories-or-files)

Add -type f to find, if you only want to count files and not directories.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
foreach f ( `find someFolder -type d` )
    echo `find $f -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -w` $f >> tmp
end
set a = `sort -rn tmp | head -n1`
set num = $a[1]
set dir = $a[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

counter=-1;

for i in `ls -ltr | grep ^d | awk '{ print $NF }'`

do

```
    count=`ls -l $i | grep ^- | wc -l`

    if [[ $count -gt $counter ]]; then
            counter=$count
            Directory=$i
    fi
```

done

echo $Directory

Answer (score 0):

Start with Dust [4e1180e5](//github.com/bootandy/dust/commit/4e1180e5) (2020-08-30), you can now do this like so:

```
-f, --filecount
Directory 'size' is number of child files/dirs not disk size
```

Example output:

```
PS C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Local> dust -f
577            ┌── Default
628          ┌─┴ User Data
629        ┌─┴ Edge
1,154    ┌─┴ Microsoft
1,901    ├── Packages
407      │     ┌── 41ad6w4a.default-release-4
493      │     │   ┌── entries
497      │     │ ┌─┴ cache2
573      │     ├─┴ 7eccqsn1.default-release-1-1597857941226
3,952    │   ┌─┴ Profiles
3,953    │ ┌─┴ Firefox
3,954    ├─┴ Mozilla
3,096    │       ┌── entries
3,100    │     ┌─┴ cache2
3,269    │   ┌─┴ 56uzf1ra.Sunday
10,341   │   │   ┌── entries
10,344   │   │ ┌─┴ cache2
10,428   │   ├─┴ 7nx7hnxa.68-edition-default
13,698   │ ┌─┴ Profiles
13,699   ├─┴ Waterfox
21,181 ┌─┴ .
```

Since this was just released, I had to build it myself with this command:

```
$env:RUSTFLAGS = '-C link-arg=-s'
cargo build --release
```