# how to find the directory/sub directory having the highest number of file

Tags: linux, unix, find, wc

I am trying to find a directory having highest number of files inside it. 
I am aware that I can find the number of files using:

```
find -maxdepth 5 -type f | wc -l
```

but this is only of use when I know which directory to check. I want to find that directory containing highest number of files.

Comment: [Possible Duplicate] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204980/how-to-find-subdirectory-of-some-directory-which-have-most-files

Comment: Isn't the directory with the most files always at the top level? So just run all the top level directories through `find <dir_name> -type f | wc -l` and sort?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list with directory names and the number of files they contain using the following nested `find` command:

```
find -maxdepth 5 -type d \
  -exec bash -c 'n=$(find {} -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf x | wc -c); echo "{} $n"' \
```

If you pipe that to:

```
find ... | sort -k2n | tail -n1
```

you'll get the directory which contains the most files.